# How to search a file and save the attribute data in the spreadsheet in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

Let's say I have alot of files formatted in .edf. I want to search each file if it has let's suppose 'hihowareyou' in it. If the file has it the program should save the name of the file in column 1 of second spreadsheet. and then further search the file for let's suppose longitude and should save the value of the attribute i.e 570degrees (as in longitude:570degrees) in column 2 of the spreadsheet.

In the following code I've found the files I need to check through recursion. I don't know how to search the files.

```
Function Recursive(FolderPath As String)

    Dim fileName As String, textData As String, textRow As String, fileNo As Integer
    Dim Value As String, Folders() As String
    Dim Folder As Variant, a As Long
    Dim Right_FolderPath As String
    ReDim Folders(0)
    If Right(FolderPath, 2) = "\\" Then Exit Function
    Value = Dir(FolderPath, &H10)
    Do Until Value = ""
        If Value = "." Or Value = ".." Then
        Else
            If GetAttr(FolderPath & Value) = 16 Then
                Folders(UBound(Folders)) = Value
                ReDim Preserve Folders(UBound(Folders) + 1)
            Else
                If Right(Value, 4) = ".edf" Then
                If Count = 4 Then
                Right_FolderPath = Right(FolderPath, 7)
                If Left(Right_FolderPath, 2) = "DR" Then

                ''''Here it goes all wrong

                    'myFile = FolderPath & Value
                    'myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename()
                    'fileNo = FreeFile 'Get first free file number
                    'Open fileName For Input As #fileNo
                    'Do While Not EOF(fileNo)
                    '    Line Input #fileNo, textRow
                    '    textData = textData & textRow
                    'Loop
                    'Close #fileNo
                    'posLat = InStr(text, "ff-ai")
                    'If Not posLat = vbNullString Then
                    '    temp(0, UBound(temp, 2)) = Value
                    'End If
                    temp(0, UBound(temp, 2)) = FolderPath
                    temp(1, UBound(temp, 2)) = Value
                    temp(2, UBound(temp, 2)) = Count ' FileLen(FolderPath & Value)
                    ReDim Preserve temp(UBound(temp, 1), UBound(temp, 2) + 1)
                End If
                End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
        Value = Dir
    Loop

    For Each Folder In Folders
        Count = Count + 1
        Recursive FolderPath & Folder & "\"
        Count = Count - 1
    Next Folder

End Function
```

And

```
Public temp() As String
```

Public Count As Integer
Function ListFiles(FolderPath As String)

```
Dim myFile As String, text As String, textline As String, posLat As Integer, posLong As Integer
Dim k As Long, i As Long
ReDim temp(2, 0)
Count = 1
If Right(FolderPath, 1) <> "\" Then
    FolderPath = FolderPath & "\"
End If
Recursive FolderPath
k = Range(Application.Caller.Address).Rows.Count
If k < UBound(temp, 2) Then
    MsgBox "There are more rows, extend user defined function"
Else
    For i = UBound(temp, 2) To k
          ReDim Preserve temp(UBound(temp, 1), i)
            temp(0, i) = ""
            temp(1, i) = ""
            temp(2, i) = ""
    Next i
End If
ListFiles = Application.Transpose(temp)
ReDim temp(0)
End Function
```

Comment: Okay.  Let's say that.  But if you want help, let's also say you make an attempt at your own solution, present your attempt, and then explain the deficiencies in your attempt.  People will be much more interested in helping you then.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but that's why I need help. :)

Answer (score 1):

StackOverlow is a community to answer specific targeted answers to help you grow as a coder. Here we typically help fix each other's code when we run into problems.
If you are looking for someone to write code for you, I suggest hiring a programmer.

Now, to get you started, I am not sure what an .edf is, but you could load the text of the file into a string, and check if that phrase "hihowareyou" is in it.

```
Dim strFilename As String: strFilename = "C:\user\desktop\yourfile.edf"
Dim strFileContent As String
Dim iFile As Integer: iFile = FreeFile
Open strFilename For Input As #iFile
strFileContent = Input(LOF(iFile), iFile)
Close #iFile
```

The above code will open the file you name in `strfilename`, and load it into a string variable.
From here, you can look in the string variable for the value you are looking for.

```
if inStr(1,strFileContent,"hihowareyou") <> 0 then
```

`instr` is a common way to do this. instr looks character by character through a string variable and returns the position where your phrase starts. If it isn't inside of your string it will return zero.

```
 if inStr(1,strFileContent,"hihowareyou") <> 0 then
     ActiveSheet.Cells(1,1)=strFilename
     longLoc = inStr(1,strFileContent,"Longitude:")
     if longLoc <> 0 then
          ActiveSheet.Cells(1,2)= Mid(strFleContent,longLoc+len("Longitude:"),10)
     end if
 end if
```

Lastly, here I provide you with an example of what to do with your strFileContent. First it checks for the "hihowareyou". If it is there, it puts the file name in Cell A1. Next, it looks for "Longitude:" if it exists, it takes the next ten characters of longitude out of the file, and places them into Cell B2

---

Sources: [Read text file into string variable](http://codevba.com/office/read_text_file_into_string_variable.htm)

Comment: Thanks that was a great help. No I don't need completely written code but in my code I tried different methods of doing this, but nothing worked. And this was a separate topic so I didn't post that code. I've edited the post now.

Comment: Plus I don't have enough time to try different combinations this time. Otherwise I don't like asking much if I have enough time to debug things myself.

Comment: Your code is giving the same error as before. I think I'm integrating it wrong with the rest of the code. Can you please have a look at it with reference to the whole code?